# Datetime.Parse() swappable formats?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

looking at the format  :  `"MMM d yyyy"`

This is working

```
var t="Mar 2013 7";
DateTime dt=DateTime.Parse(t);
```

But

```
also this :"Mar 7 2013"
and  this :"7  Mar 2013"
```

is working

looking at  :

```
new DateTimeFormatInfo()
               .GetAllDateTimePatterns()
               .Select((i,n)=>n+"    "+i)
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(f=>Console.WriteLine(f));
```

> Which is  All the standard patterns in which date and time values can be
>   formatted.

The result is :

```
0    MM/dd/yyyy
1    yyyy-MM-dd
2    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
3    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm
4    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt
5    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm
6    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt
7    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
8    MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
9    MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt
10    MM/dd/yyyy H:mm
11    MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt
12    yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
13    yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
14    yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
15    yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
16    MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
17    yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
18    MMMM dd
19    MMMM dd
20    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
21    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
22    ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
23    ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
24    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
25    HH:mm
26    hh:mm tt
27    H:mm
28    h:mm tt
29    HH:mm:ss
30    yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
31    dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
32    yyyy MMMM
33    yyyy MMMM
```

**Question  :**

- I dont see in the list the `MMM d yyyy` format. So how does it do it ?  does it try all combinations ?
- What about adding a time to format `MMM d yyyy` ? `[Mar 3 2007 13:13:13]` it also works but there is no specific format . so how does it do it?

Comment: Your assumption that DateTime.Parse() uses the patterns returned by GetAllDateTimePatterns() is not correct.  I already linked you to the Reference Source, look at System.DateTimeParse.Lex()

Comment: @HansPassant You're right. it seems it is for  all custom format strings that correspond to standard format strings.  and **not** for parsing as I assumed). thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used Reflector to look at this. It's really complicated with hundreds of lines of parsing code!

However, ultimately it winds up tokenising the input string and trying to categorise the tokens as day names, month names, years, day numbers etc.

In particular a function called `internal TokenHashValue[] CreateTokenHashTable()` has this sort of thing:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    this.InsertHash(dtfiTokenHash, this.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(i), TokenType.MonthToken, i);
}
```

It uses this (which as you can see has all the abbreviated month names) to determine if a token is a month name. There's similar code for day names.

The parsing code also checks whether one of the numbers is greater than 2 digits long. If it is, it assumes it's a year. This means (and you can verify it) that you can have a 3 digit year and it will still parse it ok. But it gets even more complicated! It also checks if the number is greater than 12, and assumes it's a year if so.

If you put two numbers each less than or equal to 12, it *still* works, but it assumes the first one is a day and the second a month (for the UK culture - I bet it's different for other cultures).

This does of course allow it to parse ambiguous dates without warning.

Upshot is: **NEVER PARSE A DATE LIKE THIS**

Always `ParseExact()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that it is using the format specifiers and not their arrangement.

From the way the literal "Mar 2013 7" is written, i doubt they can be any ambiguity in its parsing.

- Mar matches MMM exactly
- 2003 matches yyyy exactly
- 7 matches d exactly

Comment: (another example)  : ddd can be `Mon`(monday) but MMM can be `Mar`(match) they both length 3. so how does it know which is who ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I was refering to the exact format you specified above "MMM d yyyy"

Comment: @RoyiNamir this is probably why ParseExact exists .. in cases where ambiguity may exist :)

Comment: Yeah I know. But I was wondering how the _non-exact-token-location_ (datetime.parse) , does succeeds to work with swapable locations.......:-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir probably a good time to crank up reflector (or similar tool) and inspect the BCL :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to DateTime.Parse source code here:
http://typedescriptor.net/name/members/5B57671F27DBC0AEA0EB9825243834CF-System.DateTime.Parse(String,IFormatProvider,DateTimeStyles)

You can click the links to dig deeper into the private methods, but it gets complicated.  But it looks like it does lexing and parsing much like a compiler.  The string is broken up into parts (tokens) and it tries to identify if each is a year, a month, whatever.

Certainly there might be some ambiguity, e.g. maybe you meant dd-MM-yyyy but it parsed as MM-dd-yyyy.  But that's why you can specify a culture-specific IFormatProvider.